# add view in linearlayout programmatically working slowly

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-linearlayout

My goal is to add my custom view inside LinearLayout.I have custom arrayList and I would to add custom views with for loop.Here is a my code snippet

```
    public void replaceCustomView() {
    for (int i = 0; i < insertDataItems().size(); i++) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View reView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_parent_child_listing, null, false);
        final TextView parentName = reView.findViewById(R.id.tv_parentName);
        final ImageView headerImageView = reView.findViewById(R.id.header_imageView);
        final LinearLayout linearLayout_childItems = reView.findViewById(R.id.ll_child_items);
        final RelativeLayout headerLayout = reView.findViewById(R.id.header_layout);
        final RelativeLayout headerImageLayout = reView.findViewById(R.id.header_image_layout);

        parentName.setText(insertDataItems().get(i).getParentName());

        if (insertDataItems().get(i).getChildDataItems() != null) {
            headerImageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            headerImageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            for (int j = 0; j < insertDataItems().get(i).getChildDataItems().size(); j++) {
                final LayoutInflater childInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                final View childView = childInflater.inflate(R.layout.z_history_child_item, null, false);

                final TextView key = childView.findViewById(R.id.u_key);
                final TextView value = childView.findViewById(R.id.u_value);
                key.setText(insertDataItems().get(i).getChildDataItems().get(j).getKey());
                value.setText(insertDataItems().get(i).getChildDataItems().get(j).getValue());
                linearLayout_childItems.addView(childView);

            }
        } else {
            headerImageLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            headerLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e8e8e8"));
        }
        linearLayout_childItems.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (insertDataItems().get(i).getParentName().length() > 0) {
            if (insertDataItems().get(i).isAllowDisable()) {
                headerImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                linearLayout_childItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                headerImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linearLayout_childItems.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }


        } else {
            linearLayout_childItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            headerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        replaceLayout.post(() -> replaceLayout.addView(reView));

    }
}
```

I call this function like this

```
 runOnUiThread(() -> replaceCustomView());
```

Custom views adding successfully,but my problem is that in a first time activity is slowly.Android need to much time to add view.My custom array's size is 20.Is it a any way to add views step by step ,not add all views each time? 
What's a best practice ?
thanks

Comment: What is the reason that made you not to use RecyclerView for example?

Comment: maybe you are right,but as you can see I have second for loop and second child view.I tried RecyclerView,but In a scroll second childViews was dublicated in scroll up and down

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what you are trying to achieve as a hierarchy so I could suggest maybe a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use the concept of adding runtime components when the items are more. This will cause the activity to share the memory with view rendering logic and you'll be able to recycle the views. this kind of implementation can be used only when there are a few (may be 2 to 5) items and can't be achieved with recyclerview due to some UI limitations.

Hence use a RecyclerView to load the items and you can use the concept of adding custom items inside a child item to achieve this functionality.